# Show more than 3 views in SharePoint 2013 library without hiding ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript

In my SharePoint 2013 environment, I have a document library and it has more than 3 views and I want them to be shown in a tab as SharePoint out of the box only allows 3 views to be shown in tabs and rest of them come up in a dropdown.

I tried below script which is the same script in all the blogs when you search for showing multiple views in SharePoint:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(overrideSurfacePivotCount, 'clienttemplates.js');

function overrideSurfacePivotCount() {
    ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = 4;
};
```

This script worked well and showed the views in tabs but it is hiding the whole ribbon.

How can I sort this out?

Comment: If Possible then please share the snap. I too had done this in past and it worked perfectly. https://touchtheuntouchsharepoint.wordpress.com/display-more-than-3-views-link-on-list-view-page-sharepoint/...

Comment: @Akash which snap do u need. script works for me as well but i dont know why its hiding the entire ribbon.

Comment: How its hiding the whole ribbon?

Comment: @AakashMorya pls check the image . all 3 tabs are showing up and ribbon is gone.

Comment: i used sript editor webpart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments and snap its clear that you are facing problem because its hiding the ribbon.

Not to worry, this is default behavior of SharePoint. Whenever we add any `Content Editor WebPart` or `Script Editor WebPart` which contains the custom code, it will disable the ribbon from the page.

It doesn't mean that the ribbon is gone, when you will click on the List/Library area, the ribbon will be again visible to you and you can use the ribbon settings,

I faced this issue in past but I noticed this behavior. Unfortunately I was unable to find any official documentation for this.

You can click on the shown area to see the ribbon back.

[image]

let me know whether the solution worked for you.

Comment: ohh thats funny . yes it is there . Kind of weird .

Comment: Thanks Mr @Aakash . u saved my day . although we have to deal with the calls from the business users after we apply this . but cool . thanks again